# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want that if I change to mobile view, the menu items will collapse and when I click it, then it shows the menu in dropdown. It seems this code does not work, what's wrong?

I want to click this icon and show menu item in dropdown. Check this image
[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaInj.png)

This is how it looks like in desktop view [Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1LT.png)

in HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Panel</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end mr-5" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <div class="btn-group m-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-success active m-1" aria-current="page" href="home.php">View Event</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary m-1" href="add_event.php">Add Event</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <div class="btn-group m-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
              User
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="userFeedback.php">Feedback</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="userProblem.php">Issues</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="logoutChecker()" href="index.php">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

then the script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: will u explain clear

Comment: I added an image

Comment: so it is not taking any action on it when clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you have some extra text in your button

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
```

Instead of using `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` and `data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"` you have to use `data-toggle="collapse"` and  `data-target="#navbarsExample01"` take out the **bs** as you are using bootstrap 4 for more information you can check de Docs in [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/) official site.

Also don't forget to close your `nav` tag at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Panel</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end mr-5" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <div class="btn-group m-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link btn btn-success active m-1" aria-current="page" href="home.php">View Event</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary m-1" href="add_event.php">Add Event</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="btn-group m-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                User
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="userFeedback.php">Feedback</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="userProblem.php">Issues</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="logoutChecker()" href="index.php">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code for the navbar toggle button

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I already tried it, does not work

Comment: Check my snippet. I hope you will find it usefull

Comment: This is what I want, thanks for the help